# XSLT: Finding last occurence in a string

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Given a form number like:

```
ABC_12345_Q-10
```

I want to end up with:

```
ABC12345
```

So I need to find the position of the second underscore

Note that there is no standard pattern or length to any of the "sections" between the underscores (so I cannot use substring to simply eliminate the last section).

xPath 2.0 solutions are okay.

Comment: What happened with the first underscore in your sample?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for XPath 2.0 and XSLT 1.0 solutions to the more general problem when the number of underscores isn't known in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
concat(
    substring-before($s, '_'),
    substring-before(substring-after($s, '_'), '_')
)
```

Alternatively:

```
string-join(tokenize($s, '_')[position() <= 2], '')
```

Answer (score 15):

@Pavel_Minaev has provided XPath 1.0 amd XPath 2.0 solutions that work if it is known in advance that the number of underscores is 2.

**Here are solutions for the more difficult problem, where the number of undrscores isn't statically known** (may be any number):

**XPath 2.0**:

```
translate(substring($s,
                    1, 
                    index-of(string-to-codepoints($s), 
                             string-to-codepoints('_')
                             )[last()] -1
                   ),
          '_',
          ''
         )
```

**XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 >
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="s" select="'ABC_12345_Q-10'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="stripLast">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$s"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="stripLast">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'_'"/>

     <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $pDelim)">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $pDelim)"/>
       <xsl:call-template name="stripLast">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
          "substring-after($pText, $pDelim)"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to any XML document (not used), the desired, correct result is produced**:

```
ABC12345
```

Answer (score 7):

Easier solution in XSLT 2.0:

```
codepoints-to-string(reverse(string-to-codepoints(
    substring-before(
        codepoints-to-string(reverse(string-to-codepoints($s))), '_'))))
```

With 'substring-before' you will get everything *after* the *last* occurrence of your delimiter (the underscore).
If you use 'substring-after' instead, you will get everything *before* the *last* occurrence of your deliminator.

Answer (score 0):

Generalized one -

```
substring($string,1, string-length($string)-string-length(str:split($string, '_')[count(str:split($string, '_'))]))
```

Idea is to get the index of last occurrence by splitting string.

Index of last occurrence = string-length($string) - length of last string after split

Comment: A solution that depends on an extension function that only a few processors support is hardly a "generalized one".