# Xslt 1.0 - Finding the last occurence and taking string before

Tags: xml, xslt

My question is similar to [Finding last occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141847/xslt-finding-last-occurance-in-a-string)

However i need to output the whole string, just before the last occurence of the delimiter. So the out put in the example should be `ABC_12345`

Must be XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the `substring-before-last` template I implemented for another question.

[Removing the last characters in an XSLT string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119449/removing-the-last-characters-in-an-xslt-string/1119666#1119666)

It seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

**This is essentially the same solution, but in order to preserve the intermediate delimiters in the result, the following three lines must be added**:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($pText, $pDelim), $pDelim)">
  <xsl:value-of select="$pDelim"/>
</xsl:if>
```

**The whole transformation now becomes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

      <xsl:variable name="s" select="'ABC_12345_Q-10'"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="stripLast">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="stripLast">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>
        <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'_'"/>

         <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $pDelim)">
           <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $pDelim)"/>
           <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($pText, $pDelim), $pDelim)">
             <xsl:value-of select="$pDelim"/>
           </xsl:if>
           <xsl:call-template name="stripLast">
             <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
              "substring-after($pText, $pDelim)"/>
             <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
ABC_12345
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <xsl:variable name="s">string_to_cut_no_matter_how_many_underscores</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="s-tokenized" select="tokenize($s, '_')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="s_final" select="string-join(remove($s-tokenized, count($s-tokenized)),'_')"/>
```

as a function :

```
<xsl:function name="mynamespace:before-last-delimeter">
<xsl:param name="s" />
<xsl:param name="d" />

<xsl:variable name="s-tokenized" select="tokenize($s, $d)"/>

<xsl:value-of select="string-join(remove($s-tokenized, count($s-tokenized)),$d)"/>


</xsl:function>


<xsl:variable name="output" select="mynamespace:before-last-delimeter('I-only-want-before-the-last-dash','-')"/>
```

Comment: I am using xslt1.0. tokenize and remove functions are not supported

Answer (score 0):

okay XSLT 1.0 a lot more challenging :

Took me two templates

2.after-delim (outputs next value and calls itself if another delim)
3.before-last-delim ( starts the process, )

```
    <xsl:template name="after-delim">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:param name="d"/>
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="contains($s,$d)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($d,substring-before($s,$d))"/>
          <xsl:call-template name="after-delim">
            <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,$d)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="d" select="$d"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="before-last-delim">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:param name="d"/>
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="contains($s,$d)">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($s,$d)"/>
          <xsl:call-template name="after-delim">
            <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,$d)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="d" select="$d"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:call-template name="before-last-delim">


   <xsl:with-param name="s" select="'string_to_cut_with_delim'"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="d" select="'_'"/>

 </xsl:call-template>
```