# substring-before the last occurrence of any non-word character xslt 2.0 3.0

Tags: xml, substring, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Similar to this question, but in XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, and I want to break on the last non-word character (like the regex \W)

[Finding the last occurrence of a string xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166784/xslt-1-0-finding-the-last-occurence-and-taking-string-before)

The input is `REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXX`

The desired output is:

```
REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,
```

This works for one delimiter at a time, but I need to break on at least commas, spaces and dashes.

```
substring('REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXX',1,index-of(string-to-codepoints('REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXX'),string-to-codepoints(' '))[last()])
```

I am using oxygen with saxon 9.9EE and antenna house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
replace('REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXX', '(\W)\w*$', '$1')
```

However, this involves back-tracking, so it might be expensive if done on a long line. To avoid the backtracking, try

```
string-join(
   analyze-string(
      'REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXX', '\W')
      /*[not(position()=last())])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split out the string based on `tokenize()` and then use `[]` indexing or `subsequence()`, and then `join()` it back together, but the most concise approach is probably to do it all in the string realm using regex...

This XPath, based on `,` separators,

```
replace('REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXX', '(.*,).+', '$1')
```

or this XPath, based on the `\W` non-word-character,

```
replace('REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXX', '(.*\W).+', '$1')
```

will return

```
REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,
```

as requested.

Comment: Thank you, all the answers on this page worked