# Whitespace text manipulation

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML generated:

```
<InvoiceStreet>Rod House Rods Way Euro Industrial Estate</InvoiceStreet>
```

This contains white-space, I'd like to use xslt to transform it to the following:

```
<AddressLine>Rod House Rods Way</AddressLine>
<AddressLine>Euro Industrial Estate</AddressLine>
```

At the moment I'm only able to output it like so:

```
<AddressLine>Rod House Rods Way
Euro Industrial Estate</AddressLine>
```

Is there a way to do this using XSLT?

### Edit

Here is what I currently have:

```
<Address>
  <AddressLine>
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:DeliveryStreet" />
  </AddressLine>
</Address>
```

Comment: Show the code you have used so far.

Comment: See my edit, its not much but thats what I currently have relating to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output that you posted, it appears that the input has the components of the `<xsales:DeliveryAddress>` address separated by a line-feed character.

If so, you can split `xsales:DeliveryAddress` on line feeds and put each line in it's own `<AddressLine>` using a recursive template that looks for a line-feed character, creates a new `<AddressLine>` for content before the line-feed and then processes the text after it with a subsequent call to the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsales="xsales"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mailplus="http://api.mailplus.nl/rss/mailplus/">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="ItemsToShow" select="2"/>
    <xsl:param name="ShowItemDetails"/>
    <xsl:param name="ShowItemDate"/>
    <xsl:param name="Locale"/>
    <xsl:param name="Target"/>
    <xsl:template match="rss">
        <Address>
           <xsl:call-template name="AddressLines">
               <xsl:with-param name="txt" 
                               select="/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:DeliveryStreet"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
        </Address>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="AddressLines">
        <xsl:param name="txt"/>
        <!--default value for delimiter to use line-feed character -->
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#xA;'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($txt, $delimiter)">
                <AddressLine>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
                                           substring-before($txt, 
                                                            $delimiter))"/>
                </AddressLine>
                <xsl:call-template name="AddressLines">
                    <xsl:with-param name="txt" 
                                    select="substring-after($txt,
                                                            $delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <!--filter out whitespace-only lines(from trailing line feeds)-->
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space($txt)">
                    <AddressLine>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$txt"/>
                    </AddressLine>    
                </xsl:if>  
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substring Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256054.aspx), try using this piece of code snippet instead:

```
<Address>
  <AddressLine>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:DeliveryStreet,0,18)" />
  </AddressLine>
  <AddressLine>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:DeliveryStreet,19,22)" />
  </AddressLine>
</Address>
```

**Better Approach**

1. Get the length of the complete address. e.g. the length is 41 for the above provided sample string.

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="addressLength" select="string-length(/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:DeliveryStreet)" />
   ```
2. Divide the length by 2 and truncate the floating part, i.e. you will get 20

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="splitLength" select="$addressLength / 2" />
   ```
3. Now apply the substring function from zero (0) to `splitLength` variable

   ```
   substring(/*/*/*/*/*/xsales:DeliveryStreet, 0, $splitLength)
   ```

   e.g. you will get the output as `"Rod House Rods Way E"`
4. Again apply the substring function upto last occurance of space using `LastIndexOf` template.

   e.g. you will get the desired output as `"Rod House Rods Way"`

   For `LastIndexOf` template approach, you can refer to this post, [XSLT: Finding last occurance in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141847/xslt-finding-last-occurance-in-a-string)

Hope this will solve your problem for dynamic addresses, Cheers!

Comment: But the address will be dynamic, changing with each xml document, so I can't use a substring

Comment: Ok, then how would you determine from where to break the address in two parts?

Comment: That was my question, to see if its possible with the white-space?